# Convert JSON format to Array to use in data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, stringify

I'm using Angular Material datatable that requires a table to display data.

I would convert this JSON data format that backend sends to frontend

```
[{"text":"HELEO"},{"text":"HELEO"},{"text":"popopo"},{"text":":kjnkjn"},{"text":"jhjh"}]
```

To this format

```
[ { text: 'HELEO' },
  { text: 'HELEO' },
  { text: 'popopo' },
  { text: 'jhjh' } ]
```

Here's my service:

```
test: nomchamp[];
gettext(): Observable<any> {

  return this.http.get<nomchamp[]>(this.url)
    .map(res => { console.log(res); return this.test = JSON.parse(res) });

}
```

In my back-end:

```
router
.route("/")
.get(function (req, res, err) {

  // Get a database reference to our posts
  var db = admin.database();
  var ref = db.ref("/");

  // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
  ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    var list = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
      list.push(elem.val());
    })

    console.log(list);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(list))

    res.send(list);


  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    res.status(500).send(errorObject.code);
  });
});
```

I'm using stringify to be able to send data via `res.send`

Using JSON.parse I get this error :

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Without using parse , data is not printed in my datatable.

The only case where it's working is when I use `res.send(res)` in back end but what I would is using `res.write(JSON.stringify(res));`

Comment: you've got your JSON = a string right? so, `JSON.parse(thatString)` will result in an object that will be similar to the one you require. Perhaps the issue is that you are not getting JSON, but data that is already `JSON.parse`d - which is why JSON.parse fails - because JSON.parse only accepts strings to parse

Answer (score 1):

On your `list` variable, you can try this:

```
let list = [];
snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
  list.push(elem.val());
});

list = JSON.stringify(list);
list = JSON.parse(list);

res.send(list);
```

Basically, you stringify first, and then you parse it; this way, you get rid of the double quotes on each `key` in the key-value pairs within each object.

Comment: But there is no ' test' variable in back end . Wii use test ?

Comment: Whops, that was an error. It's fixed. `test` should be `list`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I may have mistunderstood what you are asking for, if so my apologies

I believe you can simply feed an angular material datatable with a object array populated by a JSON GET, I had to do it for my website and didnt want the fuss of a data table

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.name}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="desc">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.desc | slice:0:30}}... </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="tags">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tags </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.tags}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.type}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="editUser(row)"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

The variables I have added to my component.ts:

```
    displayedColumns = ['name', 'desc', 'tags', 'type'];
    projectDataURL:string = global.url + '/api/projects';
    project:any;
    dataSource;
```

Then in the constructor I have this:

```
this.subscription = this.getData.getDATA(this.projectDataURL).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(data);
            });
```

And finally I needed an interface for the data table:

```
export interface project {
    name: string;
    desc: number;
    tags: string;
    type: string;
}
```

While this isnt perfect for all use cases, for mine it worked great, hope this helps